# Missing label colors in barplot when not using add_trace

Tags: r, plotly

When creating a colored barplot without using add_trace, some label colors in the legend remain black:

```
colors <- c("blue","grey", "red", "yellow")
  data <- data.frame(time = factor(c("2010", "2011", "2010", "2011", "2010", "2011")),
                     value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
                     type = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"))

  data %>%
    plot_ly(
      type = "bar",
      x = ~time,
      y = ~value,
      color =  ~type,
      colors = colors) %>%
    layout(barmode = "relative")
```

The same issue can be discovered when using "marker = list(color = colors)" option instead of colors option directly. When using add_trace instead, everything seems to work fine. But since the number of color levels is not known in advance all the time, a solution which used add_trace (within a loop) feels unconvenient.

Comment: you mean colors in the legend?

Comment: yes, edited my initial question to make this a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
h<-ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=type))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")
ggplotly()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, maybe you could reshape your dataset from long to wide.

Here is the code:

```
library(reshape2)
data_wide <- dcast(data, time ~ type, value.var="value")
plot_ly(data_wide, x=~time) %>% 
      add_bars(y = ~A, name = "A", color= I("blue")) %>% 
      add_bars(y = ~B, name = "B", color= I("red")) %>%
      add_bars(y = ~C, name = "C", color= I("yellow")) %>% 
      layout(barmode = "stack", yaxis = list(title ="value"))
```